# Can't read data with read_html

Tags: python

I can't manage to import the data for pandas.

here the code:

```py
import pandas as pd


tables = pd.read_html('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv')
table = tables[1]

print(table)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the data using `read_csv`:

```py
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv')
tables
```

which results in:

|  | date | state | fips | cases | deaths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-21 | Washington | 53 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-22 | Washington | 53 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-01-23 | Washington | 53 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2020-01-24 | Illinois | 17 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2020-01-24 | Washington | 53 | 1 | 0 |

Note that, if you are trying to show the dataframe using a notebook(Kernel) you can use `display` on the dataframe in form of `display(tables)`, otherwise `print` works fine.

Comment: I did not know that about the display command! Nice